# How to show a small text related Image button,beside the mouse when I holding down the mouse on the Image button?

Tags: asp.net

I have an Image Button and want to show a small text beside the mouse when I holding down the mouse on the Image button

Comment: Are you talking about tool tips ? but tool tip works on mouse hover ? please elaborate more.

Answer (score 1):

use ToolTip property to show text on hover....

do you mean to show the imagebtn tooltip ? if you just need to show the tool tip try this one in aspx page

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/css.PNG" ToolTip="my testing" />
```

or in the cs page

```
ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("title", "mytesting");
```

Comment: @Zahra, Mark as Answer if found useful

Answer (score 0):

If we aren't mistaking with **holding down** as `Hover` then `ToolTip` would be best option to go with.

but if you are meaning that you want to have text when mouse button is down the you are suppose to handle `mousedown` and `mouseup` events

```
$('elementSelector').mousedown(function(){
    //...code to show text besides the element..
})

$('elementSelector').mouseup(function(){
    //...code to hide text besides the element..
})
```